# How to add second field in registration form in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, custom-field, installdata, customer-registration

I added one attribute using this code but when I try to **add another attribute then it is not working**

why?

```
<?php
namespace Icore\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $eavConfig;

    private $attributeResource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "skype");

        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'skype', [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Skype Account',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 990,
            'position' => 990,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'skype');

        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);


        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, "bussiness");
        $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'bussiness', [
            // Attribute parameters
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Check',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'bussiness');
        $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
        $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);












        /*
        //You can use this attribute in the following forms
        adminhtml_checkout
        adminhtml_customer
        adminhtml_customer_address
        customer_account_create
        customer_account_edit
        customer_address_edit
        customer_register_address
        */

        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);

        $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
    }
}
?>
```

also added **addtional.phtml**
but not showing in registration form
Magento 2 (Only showing "skype account")

```
<div class="field skype required">
    <label class="label" for="skype">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Skype Account')) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="skype" id="skype" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Skype Account')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
    </div>
</div>




<div class="field skype required">
    <label class="label" for="skype2">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Check')) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="skype2" id="skype2" value="" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Check')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false}">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field tcagreecreateaccount required">
    <div class="control">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tcagreecreateaccount" name="tcagreecreateaccount" data-validate="{required:true}" class="input-checkbox checkbox required" value="1">
        <label for="tcagreecreateaccount" class="label">
            <?= __('Custom T&C') ?>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any Idea? Please help!

Comment: What is not working?? Is this attribute found in eav_attribute table like your first one ?

Comment: yes first attribute(skype) is showing in magento 2 tables 

not showing second attribute

Comment: You added both attribute in same file right? I mean you added first installed module then added second attribute, i guess

Comment: yes................

Comment: yes but i need simplification for mycode in  installdata.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the second **attribute** isn't installed in magento table, since because **InstallData.php** and **InstallSchema.php** will trigger when the module is installed. So the second time after you modified your InstallData.php for second attribute the file won't trigger out there.

Magento 2 has a feature of **UpgradeData.php** and there we have to define our module version to upgrade data and the module version has to be declared in **module.xml** in your module.

For more information [visti here](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-and-upgrade-database-in-magento-2/)

UpgradeData feature you can use when your module went to production and next time when you want to install new attribute in the sense you can use this feature and as of now I hope you extension didn't went to production yet so you can follow below steps to get it install your second attribute.

Steps to uninstall a module from database :

Run the below query in you database,

```
 DELETE from setup_module where module = 'Icore_Module';
```

then modify your **InstallData.php** as per your requirement then run below commands to install the module

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: can i get your mail id bro